# Is there a way to leverage inheritance when including a parameter of the base class in a constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

From what I've read, there doesn't appear to be a good way to convert a class a base class to an inheriting class.

Following the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565736/convert-base-class-to-derived-class) question, I've gone ahead and just created a constructor that takes an instance of the base class as a parameter.

The constructor looks like this:

```
public DerivedClass(BaseClass base) {
    this.Id = base.Id;
    this.Foo = base.Foo;
    // ..
    this.NewProperty = SomeNewValue;
}
```

etc. This also means that if the base class gets a new property, the constructor in the derived class also needs to be modified in order to copy that property.

**Is there a way to leverage the fact that the derived class inherits from the base class to make this constructor less fragile?**

Comment: Instead of posting a link could you post your code along with the rest of it .. that way people don't have to jump back and forth

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? Under what circumstances do you have an Animal in hand and need to construct a Tiger?

Comment: In the circumstances that I had a bunch of animals, I filtered down to the ones that I want to make tigers, and now I want to have a bunch of tigers instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you haven't fully grasped inheritance and you've over-thought what you need to do.

> I've gone ahead and just created a constructor that takes an instance of the base class as a parameter.

You don't need to do this when extending (inheriting from) a base class, you only do this when wrapping a class.

> Is there a way to leverage the fact that the derived class inherits from the base class to make this constructor less fragile?

Yes: use constructor overloading. Given this base class:

```
public class MyBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set;}
}
```

you *could* do this:

```
public class MyExtendedClass : MyBase 
{
    public MyExtendedClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

but better still is to leverage constructor overloading like this, where constructor parameters are passed through to the base class constructor:

```
public class MyBase
{

    public MyBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set;}
}

public class MyExtendedClass : MyBase 
{
    public MyExtendedClass(string name) : base (name) {   }
}
```

You would tend to pass in values on the constructor for properties that you want to be immutable. For the others, you can take advantage of inline initialization:

```
var myNewClass = new MyExtendedClass() { Name = "blah" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a protected constructor to the base class that carries out the assignments and then just pass the base class down to it as a parameter:

```
protected BaseClass(BaseClass source)
{
    this.Id = source.Id;
    this.Foo = source.Foo;
    ...
}
```

Thereby keeping the code to duplicate the base class in the base class itself?