# Is it possible to get derived class' property if it is in the form of base class?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, converters

I have three classes,namely `ClassA`,`ClassB`,`ClassC`.
**ClassC** inherits from **ClassB**,and **ClassB** inherits from **ClassA**.They are not **static** classes.

**ClassC** has a unique property,let it be "Name",which is **not** inherited from class B or C.

Suppose I create an instance of ClassC,namely **instanceOfClassC**:

```
ClassC instanceOfClassC = new ClassC();
instanceOfClassC.Name = "name of class";
```

Then I create an instance of **ClassA** and assign **instanceOfClassC** to it:

```
ClassA instanceofClassA = instanceOfClassC;
```

Then my question is: **Is it possible to get "name of class" from instanceOfClassA?** I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565736/convert-base-class-to-derived-class),but still haven't lost my heart. I'm writing a Converter, so I hope to get a solution without redesigning my classes.

Comment: No, you have to cast it back to ClassC

Comment: ... but yes it is possible.

Comment: @Rawling Then how to do it...

Comment: "Is it possible to get "name of class" from instanceOfClassA?"
Yes. `GetType()` method returns the actual object's type.

Comment: This is a classic. Looks to me like ClassC should have a ClassB as opposed to being a ClassB

Comment: @TonyHopkinson How can you possibly get that from three tiers of classes and one property?

Comment: @Rawling Because Class C has a property that the op wants to access through ClassA. So the options are cast, or put the property on classA even though it isn't a property of A. Course the hierarchy could be wrong. NB either option could be the most pragmatic solution, but as soon as I see something like this, I ask myself the Is A , has A question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast `ClassA` back to `ClassC` to access members on `ClassC`:

```
ClassC instanceOfClassC = new ClassC();
instanceOfClassC.Name = "name of class";

ClassA insanceofClassA = instanceOfClassC;
// insanceofClassA.Name not possible as ClassA does not have a member "Name".

ClassC c = (ClassC)insanceofClassA;
string name = c.Name;
```

Comment: Um...I don't understand.Since ClassA does not have a property of **Name**,where is the **"name of class"** kept in instanceofClassA?

Comment: In simple terms, `insanceofClassA` is a reference to `instanceOfClassC`. `insanceofClassA` is really a `ClassC` inside a `ClassA`.

Answer (score 1):

Naming the variables `instanceOfClassA` is misleading. An instance of `ClassC` will always be an instance of that class, even after assigning it to a variable of type `ClassA`. However when using a *variable* of type `ClassA`, the compiler does not know if this is your `ClassC` *instance*, or if you assigned a different `ClassA` instance to it.

To access `ClassC` members you need to cast it back, after optionally verifying that you are indeed dealing with a `ClassC` type:

```
ClassC myClassC = instanceOfClassA as ClassC;
if (myClassC != null)
{
    // It's a class C and it's been cast already
}
```

or

```
if (instanceOfClassA is ClassC)
{
    // It's a class C, cast it
    ClassC myClassC = (ClassC)instanceOfClassA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `instanceofClassA` is declared as `ClassA` and it's value type is `ClassB`. It's possible get value of property with Reflection.

```
public T2 GetPropertyValue<T1, T2>(T1 sourceObject, string propertyName) {

    var value = typeof(T1).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(sourceObject);
    return (T2)value;
}
```

But, using reflection in some scenario has performance pitfall.

See: [How costly is .NET reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection)