# How to convert List<type> to User Class

Tags: c#, list, converters

i try to understand how can i convert List to my class, example:

```
class Program
{
    public class Integner : List<int> 
    {
        
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);

        Program.ShowList((Integner)list);
    }

    static void ShowList(Integner list)
    {
        list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    }
}
```

How I can convert List to my class Integner, which extends List?

Answer (score 1):

> How I can convert List to my class Integner, which extends List?

You must define such a conversion; because `Integner` is a *subclass* of `List<int>`, you cannot just perform a cast.

To define the conversion, you could use an implicit operator:

```
public class Integner : List<int> 
{
    public Integner(IEnumerable<int> collection) : base(collection) { }
    public static implicit operator Integner(List<int> list) => new Integner(list);
}
```

Which would make this syntax valid:

```
Program.ShowList((Integner)list);
```

Note the use of `List<T>`'s "copy constructor", which allows a new list to be created from any `IEnumerable<T>`.

Having defined this constructor, it may be clearer to create a new `Integner` explicitly, rather than using the operator which somewhat obfuscates the fact that a new instance is being created:

```
Program.ShowList(new Integner(list));
```

---

As an aside, inheriting from `List<T>` is rarely a good idea: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Answer (score -1):

You can't cast from the base class to the derived class in this case. I think the following answer will help you a little more -

[Convert base class to derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565736/convert-base-class-to-derived-class)

Comment: Referring to another answer can better be done using the "Close As Duplicate" option (which you might not see if your reputation isn't yet high enough to see it) or else using a comment below the question.

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, I am aware of that, however I am way off in terms of privileges being a new user.

Comment: Then it's better to just hold it in, or add it as a comment, because this way your rep is going down rather than up...

Comment: @PeterB I guess, if someone is going to downvote that is... Thanks all the same.